# Populate combobox with collection other than the one the Grid it is in is bound to

Tags: wpf, binding

I have the following code:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ItemTypes}">
            ...

            <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Description:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Manufacturer:" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Short Name:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
        </Grid>
```

The ItemTypes that the Grid's DataContext is set with, comes from a ViewModel that holds yet another collection. The Manufacturer Combobox that's inside this Grid needs to be filled with the other collection. I tried this:

```
     ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
 AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.companies}"
```

But it didn't work. How can I get the combobox to fill with the other collection than the one the Grid is bound to?

ViewModel code:

```
    public class ItemTypeViewModel
    {
        #region private fields
        private ICollectionView collectionView;
        private IItemTypeService itemTypeService;
        #endregion

        #region automatic properties
        public ObservableCollection<ItemTypeViewModel> ItemTypes { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<Company> companies { get; private set; }
        #endregion properties

        #region constructors
        public ItemTypeAdminViewModel(IItemTypeService itemTypeService)
        {
            this.itemTypeService = itemTypeService;
            Initialize();
            collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemTypes);
        }
        #endregion

        #region private methods
        private void Initialize()
        {
            //TODO figure out if I should I wrap in Try/Catch here
            ItemTypes = new ObservableCollection<ItemTypeViewModel>(itemTypeService.GetItemTypes());
            companies = itemTypeService.GetCompanies();
        }
        #endregion

        #region commands
        public ICommand GoToFirst
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst(),
                    () => collectionView.CurrentPosition >= 1);
            }
        }

        public ICommand GoToLast
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToLast(),
                    () => collectionView.CurrentPosition < (ItemTypes.Count - 1));
            }
        }

        public ICommand NextCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToNext(),
                    () => collectionView.CurrentPosition < (ItemTypes.Count - 1));
            }
        }

        public ICommand PreviousCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => collectionView.MoveCurrentToPrevious(),
                    () => collectionView.CurrentPosition >= 1);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your view model is set to `Window.DataContext` and your other collection `MyOtherCollection` is a property in the view model. Change your `ComboBox` to the following:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.MyOtherCollection}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I tried it and it doesn't work for me. Still nothing gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say just don't set the `DataContext` on the `Grid`. Instead, bind each item individually. It's difficult to give further advice unless you give further information - specifically, your VM.

Comment: The Grid with its DataContext set to ItemTypes (the XAML code I posted) is a User Control. It has the ItemTypes coming from the ViewModel that the Window it contains is set to. You still think that setting each item is mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

What's assigned to datacontext of the view in its constructor. If you assign view's datacontext to be the viewmodel through constructor injection, you should be able to directly bind as `ItemsSource="{Binding companies}"`

Comment: The XAML code of the form is actually a User Control. The data it gets (e.g ItemTypes in the grid) comes from a page that contains this User Control, and has its DataContext set.